# Clamping diodes or TVS

Tags: input

When should be clamping diodes preferred over one-directional TVS for input sanitation?  Consider only digital inputs, not power lines. Clamping diodes seem to be [recommended](http://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/apr/protecting-inputs-in-digital-electronics) so I worry I might be missing something.

- Single one-directional TVS can supply operation of both clamping diodes (over/under voltage protection)
- Clamping diodes are not faster: small signal Schottky diodes switch in tens of picoseconds ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode)), beefy models can take much longer. Littlefuse's [SMBJ](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/tvs_diodes/littelfuse_tvs_diode_smbj_datasheet.pdf.pdf) series switch in 1.0ps.
- With clamping diodes the power supply must be able to absorb the charge coming from the input. This can be fatal for badly designed supplies.
- TVS with low BV can have high leakage current but that is problematic with Schottky diodes as well

Comment: Diodes are generally much cheaper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schottky diodes are generally much faster. Take the SMBJ TVS you linked. It is a general purpose TVS and the recovery time (tr) is not even specified. On Figure 4, you can infer that tr is in the microsecond range.

There are TVS specifically designed for ESD which are much faster. Take [PESD5V0S1](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/580924/NXP/PESD5V0S1B.html) for example, tr is inferred to be in the nanosecond range.

Check out the capacitance -- SMBJ5.0: >10000pF, PESD5V: 45pF. The SMBJ is not suitable for many (if not most) digital signal applications.

It is true that TVS such as SMBJ can absorb a significant amount of energy and do that directly. They are designed more for power applications but are not useful for most signal applications directly (more so when coupled with their high leakage current).

Take the SMBJ5.0, it is intended for 5V but with a breakdown voltage of 6.4V-7.0V. That is way above one diode drop above 5V or the maximum condition of most 5V digital logic. If one try to cheat a little and work in a lower voltage TVS, then the leakage current goes up even higher.

Comment: Recovery time, i.e. time taken once the diode is conducting to recover to off state might not be so important. A few microseconds or even longer off-service time after a protection event could be no problem.

Comment: Are there applications where the recovery time is important? - The TVS is a protection element so it operates only in failure mode.

Comment: Yes, I have my terminology mixed up. tr is the ramp-up time of the testing waveform. For the SMBJ, it is designed for voltage ramp of microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

- CMOS has always had this nasty inherent vertical layered PNPN junction which cannot be avoided in its fabrication. This is sometimes a fatal crowbar SCR across the supply rails thru these semiconductor layers which can shutdown your supply or damage the device, if it overheats or draws excess current. The only way to protect these inputs and outputs is to ensure they do not exceed either supply rail by 0.3V at 5mA. Hence all CMOS has current limited protection diodes which are small to reduce input capacitance thus are limited to low current over voltage.

Additional diodes or TVS may be added to long wires and the current must still be limited to <5mA by adding a series R between outside clamp and inside ESD protection diodes.

- another example of diode clamps are across inductive loads that are switched such that the diode is reverse in normal operation and becomes forward biased to carry the inductive load current until it decays.

The choice on whether to use TVS or clamp diodes depends on the expected energy of a pulse on the signal line.  TVSs are like uber-Zener diodes with lower ESR  than typical Zener diodes and are designed to allow output signals to be clamped on long lines but allow normal voltages like 0-3.3 or. 0-5.0 to pass unimpeded.

TVSs still have large capacitance e.g. (900 pF) compared to ESD input clamp diodes 1pF and may reduce slew rate of high speed and high impedance at the end of a long inductive wire.

THe TVS diode rated for 1W abs. max. can handle 100W for short durations (us) but even with low ESR values can rise to 3x the rated voltage with 50A spikes.   Thus this can be used for clamping an automotive supply voltage with R or L input current limiting to electronics when an inductive load is dumped, like when AC clutch is turned off.

TVS can switch arc transients with picosecond transition times near arc to suppress high V transients within 1ns according to datasheet.   Clamp diodes may be slower at same cost. This can be useful for 30kV ESD protection using the human hand model of 300pF , not lightning. High slew rate transients are often slowed down using ferrite beads on power semi leads in high power bridge drivers along with clamp diodes or built-in protected Avalanche switches.

> The choice always depends on defining the potential transient voltage,
>   Joules, or Watts and duration , voltage rise to determine the lowest
>   cost yet adequate protection for any known susceptible device.

Comment: The inputs have high impedance so adding 10k+ resistor between inside and outside clamp should be OK in many applications. However, how to fit in the 0.3V drop maximum? Power Schottky diodes have drops from 0.5V to 0.7V. Should I put small resistance in front of the outside clamp to limit current through the upper clamp so smaller Schottky diode can be used?

Comment: that is good practice